# java equation with percentages

Tags: java, calculator, percentage, equation

I am trying to create a program that outputs the grade the user needs in order to get a grade in a class when asked for certain data. Essentially a Final Exam Calculator. It asks for the user to input their current grade, the grade wanted, and the weight of the exam. I know it's been done before but I need this for my semester project and I don't want to copy someone else's work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);

    double g,r,w,f;
    System.out.println("Enter your current class grade *Ex. 98* :  ");
    g = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter your required class grade *Same format*:  ");
    r = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the weight of your Final Exam *Same format*:  ");
    w = in.nextInt();

    f = (r - (100 - w) * g)/w;

    System.out.println("The grade you need on your final exam is: " + f +"%");



}
```

I know that the equation works because I tested it with a calculator, but I need the output to be a percentage. g, r, and w need to also be percentages but I don't know how to write an equation that works with percentages entered by the user.

When I ran the program with g=75, r=80, and w=40, it outputs 75.875% when the answer should have been 87.5%.

Comment: java.util.Scanner is added. The only problem is the calculation.

Comment: what is the value of `w`?

Comment: You seem to be asking for help with [arithmetic](https://www.helpingwithmath.com/by_subject/percentages/per_calculating.htm), not programming... It's also unclear how you mean to use the weight variable. Is it the weight of the final exam or the weight of all previously completed exams? I can guess, but this is math, not hangman.

Comment: I’m trying to find the grade the user needs to get on their final exam in order to have a certain percentage in the class. The weight is of their final exam.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns arithmetic, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the numbers that you have provided, I assume that you mistyped the value of w as '4-' instead of 40

Your arithmetic is incorrect.

The correct equation is :

```
f = (100 * r - (100 - w) * g)/w;
```